# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.setState') when Removing object from Flatlist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

So I'm learning Flatlists at the moment in React Native, and I'm trying to write a function to remove the item in a Flatlist by using onLongPress in a Button, this the the example of an item as it shows in the Terminal:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "Friday": false,
    "Monday": true,
    "Saturday": false,
    "Sunday": false,
    "Thursday": false,
    "Tuesday": false,
    "Wednesday": false,
    "key": 0.08631781113770953,
    "workoutName": "",
  },
]
```

and this is the function I'm using, which I followed a Tutorial to get:

```
removeItem(item){
    this.setState({
       workoutList: this.state.workoutList.filter((item)=>item.key !== item.key)
    });
}
```

this is where I call the function:

```
openTwoButtonAlert = () => {
    Alert.alert(
       'Delete Workout',
      'Are you sure to delete this Workout?',
      [
        {text: 'Delete', onPress: this.removeItem(item)},

        {text: 'Cancel', 
           style: 'cancel',
           
        },
      ],
    );
  }
```

this is my Flaltist:

```
 <FlatList
              data={this.state.workoutList}
              keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.toString()}
              renderItem={({ index, item}) => (
                <View style={{padding:20}}>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("WorkoutCreated", {
                    workoutName: item.workoutName,
                    Monday: item.Monday,
                    Tuesday: item.Tuesday,
                    Wednesday: item.Wednesday,
                    Thursday: item.Thursday,
                    Friday: item.Friday,
                    Saturday: item.Saturday,
                    Sunday: item.Sunday,
                  })} 
                  onLongPress={()=>this.openTwoButtonAlert(index)}>
                    <Text>{item.workoutName}</Text>       
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              )}
            />
```

the state to update is workoutList and I'm using a class component,and when I launch the code it returns back the error: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.setState')` thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Share your complete code. where are you calling `removeItem`?

Comment: I edited the code above

Answer (score 0):

Try this way (Updated)

```
<FlatList
   ...
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.toString()} // update here also
    renderItem={({item, index}) => ( // **** updated here ****
       .....
       onLongPress={() => this.openTwoButtonAlert(index)}
       ...
    )
   ... 
/>

openTwoButtonAlert = (index) => { // updated here
    Alert.alert(
      ...
        {text: 'Delete', onPress: () => this.removeItem(index)}, // change here
      ...
    );
}

removeItem(index){
    // updated code of removing item from list
    const newData = [...this.state.workoutList]; // this code is making clone of the data list
    newData.splice(index, 1); // remove item from list
    this.setState({workoutList: newData}); // reset data to list       
}
```

Comment: I updated the code above as I'm using it, with that change now it returns the error: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: item`

Comment: @Salvo you should have `item` where you calling `onPress` because you are expecting `item` as param in `removeItem` method.

Comment: it still returns the error, I don't know if it's because I don't use `item` in the Flatlist, I inserted the Flatlist in code above, so you can see what I'm doing wrong in there

Comment: I use onLongPress to open the Alert warning and confirm deleting the item

Comment: Probably the error is because you're not passing the ```item``` param of the ```FlatList``` in the ``ònLongPress``` prop. Pass the item in its param like this ```onLongPress={()=>this.openTwoButtonAlert(data.item) }```

Comment: @Salvo I have updated my code, please check

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani I've applied your suggestion and now instead of deleteing the item, it creates the same one again and returns the warning:  `Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `0.31877934081296233`.`

Comment: @Salvo I have updated my complete answer please check

Comment: @Salvo Update your `keyExtractor` code as well to get rid of the warning

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani I've applied all the changes and when I go to delete nothing happens, it doesn't return errors or anyhting, it just remains there, I've applied a `console.log(index)`, and it returns `undefined` so that's probably the reason

Comment: @Salvo update `renderItem` code as I have updated please check

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani ok I updated the flatlist above with the current one I'm using, now the index returns the number 0, and no error shows when running the code, but it still doesn't get deleted.